# idle-python3.2 not starting: complains of NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle, python-3.2

running linux mint 13

idle-python3.2 did work from the terminal before, now it does not. 
Calling idle-python3.2 from the terminal throws the error below BUT I can run Idle by double clicking on the script!

Here's the very simple script that broke it all(?)
http://pastebin.com/pP9An3UU
FWIW, the script does not appear to work either (nothing happens when I run it).

Here's the error in the terminal when trying to run Idle3.2 from the terminal:

```
File "tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    tk = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

here's the full error
http://pastebin.com/J5AfAQyV

I know tkinter is not installed by default... but it IS installed

```
python3-tk is already the newest version.
python3-tk set to manually installed.
```

I've checked the system monitor and killed all obvious python instances running in the background.

But, still no joy.

Here's a video of the error:
http://youtu.be/oCLOJR2rktI

Your help for a fix is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you either a) named your little test program "tkinter.py", or b) you have another file in the same directory named "tkinter.py". If that is the case, when you do `from tkinter import *`, you are *not* importing the real tkinter but rather importing the local file.

If you named your file "tkinter.py", rename it. Also, if there is a file named "tkinter.pyc", remove it.

Comment: Thank you! My little test program appears to be the source of the problem! It was named "tkinter.py". A real n00b error!